# Progress bar UI custom design in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, user-interface

I'm quite new to react native and javascript and I have to make this type of progress bar with the four categories.

Can anyone help or suggest to me how can I achieve this UI in react native for android and iOS on both platforms?

The expected output screenshot is attached below:
[image]

However, I don't need the user interaction or progress animation, I just have to show the fix progress in percentage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an approximation of your component built in React Native, [you'll need to add `react-native-linear-gradient` to your dependencies beforehand](https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient)

I have also created a demo on Expo (you should test it on the target device) that uses expo's version of the linear gradient library. https://snack.expo.dev/@sabihi/milestone-progressbar

```jsx
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.progressLabels}>
        <Text style={styles.progressLabel}>Beginner</Text>
        <View style={styles.progressLabel}></View>
        <Text style={styles.progressLabel}>Amateur</Text>
        <View style={styles.progressLabel}></View>
        <Text style={styles.progressLabel}>Elite</Text>
        <View style={styles.progressLabel}></View>
        <Text style={styles.progressLabel}>Master</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.progressContainer}>
        <LinearGradient colors={["rgb(7, 14, 60)", "rgb(86, 90, 106)"]} style={styles.progress}/>
        <View style={styles.milestonesContainer}>
          <View style={styles.milestone}/><View style={styles.milestone}/><View style={styles.milestone}/>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    // paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },

  progressLabels: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    width: "100%",
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  progressLabel: {
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontFamily: "sans-serif",
    width: "14.3%",
    textAlign: "center"
  },

  progressContainer: {
    position: "relative",
    height: 100
  },
  progress: {
    marginLeft: "5%",
    marginTop: 5,
    width: "90%",
    height: 30,
    // backgroundColor: "rgb(7, 14, 60)",
    borderRadius: 15
  },

  milestonesContainer: {
    marginLeft: "5%",
    position: "absolute",
    width: "100%",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row"
  },
  milestone: {
    height: 40,
    width: "30%",
    // backgroundColor: "white",
    borderColor: "rgb(7, 14, 60)",
    borderLeftWidth: 1,
    borderRightWidth: 1,
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, I found your answer super helpful. I have a similar use-case and I have an integer value on a scale of (0-10). I want to use this as progress bar to indicate those integer values. I am new to react-native. I have that variable but I am not sure how to use it with above code. Can someone help on this please?

Comment: @muhammad-aqeel please go ahead and describe